# Convert Observable from createSelector using ngrx and rxjs (TS2740: Type 'MemoizedSelector error)

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx

So my traditional way of retrieving data from the ngrx store was:

```
public getUser(): Observable<IUser> {
  return this.store.select(store => store.users.selectedUser);
}
```

but I am trying to convert to use createSelecor (ngrx  15) thus tried to:

```
 public getUser(): Observable<IUser> {
        const user = createSelector((state: IAppState) => state.users,
            (userState) => {
                return userState;
            }
        );
        return user;
    }
```

but getting an error of:

```
TS2740: Type 'MemoizedSelector<IAppState, IUserState, (s1: IUserState) => IUserState>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<IUser>': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.
```

So my question is how do I get an Observable from `createSelecor`  so I can later do:

```
        this.storeSelector.getUser().subscribe((a) => {
            console.log(a);
        });
```

TypeScript is not happy with: `Observable<IUser>`
return type.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in your answer probably doesn't memoize as you are declaring a new selector each time.

You don't really need the `getUserMemoize` function either now given the simplicity of its body which you can use directly.

```
export const getUser = createSelector((state: IAppState) => state.users,
  (userState) => userState.selectedUser
 ));

...
public getUserMemoize(){
  return this.store.select(getUsers);
}

// Or use directly
const users$ = this.store.select(getUsers);
```

Or combining as in your followup:

```
const getUsers = createSelector((state: IAppState) => state.users, (userState) => userState);
const getConfig = createSelector((state: IAppState) => state.config, (userState) => userState);

const getCombined = createSelector(
  getUsers,
  getConfig,
  (users, config) => ({ users, config}));

const combined$ = this.store.select(getCombined);
```

Do not recall `createSelector` as you will get a new instance which lacks the state of previous one so it can't perform memoization.

You should be able to use `combined$` directly rather than wrapping it in a function.

Comment: mmm I see, so I should not createSelecor over and over, otherwise memoization won't take effect? ... so if I have a helper class, would this be the ideal way to call it ( I updated my solution above, see: getUserCombinesExample3 ... please let me know if this would be ideal)

Comment: You appear to have significantly edited the code in my answer so it bears little resemblance to what I wrote, and the changes again mean that memoization will be broken. And no, your own updated answer is not the correct  way to combine selectors.

Comment: I've rolled your changes back so as not to mislead anyone else reading this.

Answer (score 0):

figured this is the way:

```
    ...
    private selectorCombined$;
    ...
getUserCombinesExample5(): Observable<{ u: IUser, c: IUIConfigState }> {
        if (!this.selectorCombined$) {
            alert('create instance once selectorCombined$');
            const users = createSelector((state: IAppState) => state.users, (userState) => userState);
            const config = createSelector((state: IAppState) => state.config, (userState) => userState);
            this.selectorCombined$ = createSelector(users, config,
                (i_users1, i_config) => {
                    return {u: i_users1, c: i_config};
                },
            );
        }
        return this.store.select(this.selectorCombined$)
            .pipe(map((v: { u: IUser, c: IUIConfigState }) => {
                    return v;
                })
            );
    }
```

comments?

Comment: This is overcomplicated and still circumvents memoization. See my updated answer above.